# Has Facebook graph API stopped return expires when exchanging for long-lived tokens?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK to obtain user's access token. The code is copied from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0
They should be like below:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('your redirect URL here');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
// Use the login url on a link or button to redirect to Facebook for authentication
```

And then in the redirect action:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  var_dump($session);
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
```

A couple of weeks ago, I could see the expires value was returned from the API. But now, only access_token is returned.
Has Facebook changed its API output?

Comment: If you want to know what the API actually returns, then you should make that API call “by hand” – otherwise you won’t be able to tell if it’s not maybe just the PHP SDK that is hiding that information from you.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I was actually inspecting the $session variable using XDebug. The var_dump is just another way to say how I inspected it.

Answer (score 1):

Update : I learned the extended token was created with an account that scoped offline access. I backed all out and removed that access and the token is extended 60 days.

It appears that extending the token returns 0 instead of an expiration date because it never expires. Extending a token started breaking my app because it was returning 0. It used to return a timestamp about 60 days out. I took the extended token to the Open Graph Debugger, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ The value for Expires = Never.

Can anyone confirm this or point towards updated documentation. The docs still say 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

The above code looks fine but for,

Token expiration Sol :
Facebook has changed its endpoint redirect url for long live tokens,

Now the end point is :
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=...&client_secret=...&redirect_uri=...&client_id=...

Also generally facebook bydefault provides short live access tokens which expires in 2hours if you want a long live token access which has life for 60days than you can use following function.
[link for ref](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0#getlonglivedsession)

$longLivedSession = $facebookSession->getLongLivedSession();

echo $longLivedSession->getToken();

check following links which highlights more information related to long live tokens.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: _“in your catch statement there is an extra '\' before exception”_ – that’s not an error, it just means `Exception` class is in the default [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) …

Comment: @WisdmLabs, thanks for you answer but I didn't look for it. Those are documented very well in FB developer site. What I wanted to know is why I was using the sample code from FB PHP SDK but I didn't get the expires value.